# Is yield break equivalent to returning Enumerable<T>.Empty from a method returning IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

These two methods appear to behave the same to me

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetNothing()
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetLessThanNothing()
{
    yield break;
}
```

I've profiled each in test scenarios and I don't see a meaningful difference in speed, but the `yield break` version is slightly faster.

Are there any reasons to use one over the other? Is one easier to read than the other? Is there a behavior difference that would matter to a caller?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you intend to always return an empty enumerable then using the `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` syntax is more declarative IMHO.

The performance difference here is almost certainly not significant.  I would focus on readability over performance here until a profiler showed you it was a problem.

Answer (score 23):

`IEnumerable<T>` methods with `yield break` or `yield return` in their bodies gets transformed to state machines. In this kind of methods you can't mix yield returns with traditional returns. What I mean is that if you yield something in some part of the method, you can't return a ICollection in another.

In the other hand, suppose you're implementing a method with return type `IEnumerable<T>` by adding items to a collection, and then returning a readonly copy of the collection. If by some reason you want to just return an empty collection you can't do a `yield break`. All you can do is just return `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

If you've profiled both ways, and there's no significant change, then you can just forget about it :)

Comment: +1 for clarifying the generic-enumerable/yield approach vs. the collection-building method, i.e. each approach *forces* a reason to use one or the other.

Comment: Id say IEnumerable yields behave like "Python Generators that can be reiterated over". The advantage of IEnumerable is not having to MemLoad the entire list or result at once, so using yields is consistently more efficient than making an entire list or array and returning it

Answer (score 8):

> I've profiled each in test scenarios and I don't see a meaningful difference in speed, but the yield break version is slightly faster.

I'm going to guess that your profiling tests did not include program startup speed. The `yield` construct works by generating a class for you. This extra code is great when it provides logic you need, but if not, it just adds to disk I/O, working set size, and JIT time.

If you open a program containing your test methods in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and turn off enumerator decompilation, you'll find a class named `<GetLessThanNothing>d__0` with a dozen or so members. Its `MoveNext` method looks like this:

```
bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
{
    int num = this.<>1__state;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        this.<>1__state = -1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`EmptyEnumerable` works by lazily creating a static empty array. Perhaps checking whether the array needs to be created is the reason `EmptyEnumerable` is slower than `yield break` in isolated benchmarking, but it would likely take a whole lot of iterations to overcome the startup penalty, and either way would be unlikely to be noticeable overall, even in a "death by a thousand perf papercuts" scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Funny thing, I read this post this morning, and few hours later I was hit by this example -- found the difference when you have more code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CoalesceEmpty<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    if (coll == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    else
         return coll;
}
```

You cannot change the first return to yield break, because you would have to change the second return as well (to longer version).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that `yield break` would instantiate at least one less object than what `return Enumerable.Empty<string>()` would do. Additionally, there may be some checks that you would be short-circuiting with `yield break`. And if nothing else, it's one less function wrapper that your stack goes through which would be detectable although not noticeable.

However, I agree with the other answer posted that .Empty is the "preferred" way of doing this.

Comment: Why would you think that? `Enumerable.Empty<string>` could return the same thing every time - and I believe it does, in fact. There's no need for it to create anything at all, after the first call. I doubt very much that the C# compiler would spot that it could do that for the `yield break` case.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - You're right. The yield break version is indeed instantiating the class `yield` generates each time. `Enumerable.Empty` is smart enough to cache

Comment: Wouldn't it have to at least return a cloned copy (i.e. a new instantiation)?

Comment: @Jaxidian, why would it have to clone it? It's always returning a readonly empty sequence.

Comment: Is it in fact readonly? I didn't think that was the case, but of course I learn something new every day. :-)

Comment: @Jaxidian - It returns an IEnumerable<> so there are no ways to modify it, and since it is empty you can't modify the contents either.

Answer (score 0):

If you do **not** intend to **always** return an **empty** enumerable, then I would like to add that `yield` is *lazy*, i.e. it will be evaluated every time the enumerator is queried.

The following test demonstrates the laziness:

```
public void TestYieldEnumerator()
{

    var returnItems = false;
    var e = getEmptyEnumerator();
    var y = getEmptyYield();

    Assert.AreEqual(e.Count(), 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(y.Count(), 0);

    returnItems = true;
    Assert.AreEqual(e.Count(), 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(y.Count(), 1); //the second query returns items

    IEnumerable<string> getEmptyEnumerator() => !returnItems 
                                                ? Enumerable.Empty<string>() 
                                                : new List<string>() { "item" };

    IEnumerable<string> getEmptyYield()
    {
        if (returnItems) yield return "item";
    }
}
```